# Class not found when trying to index documents using Solr with Symfony2

Tags: symfony, solr, indexing, solarium

I am very new to Solr and I am probably missing something simple however, having followed [Xavier Briand's](http://xavierbriand.github.com/training-solr/#/uber-feature-again) presentation I have set up Symfony2, Solarium and Nelmio\SolariumBundle.

```
"nelmio/solarium-bundle": "2.0.*@dev",
"solarium/solarium": "3.0.*"
```

Having implemented a toSolrDocument method for my doctrine php object.

```
public function toSolrDocument(\Solarium_Document_ReadWrite $doc)
{
    $doc->id          = $this->getId();
    $doc->description = $this->getTitle();
    $doc->path        = "path";

    return $doc;
}
```

I am faced with the following error.

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to ::toSolrDocument() must be an instance of Solarium_Document_ReadWrite, instance of Solarium\QueryType\Update\Query\Document given, called in Controller.php

The controller calling this toSolrDocument method has the following function

```
public function indexItems(){

    $client = $this->get('solarium.client');

    // get an update query instance
    $update = $client->createUpdate();

    // create documents
    $documents = array();

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $repo = $em->getRepository('<Bundle>:<Object>');
    $items = $repo->findAll();


    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $documents[] = $item->toSolrDocument($update->createDocument());
    }

    // add the documents and a commit command to the update query
    $update->addDocuments($documents);
    $update->addCommit();

    // this executes the query and returns the result
    $result = $client->update($update);
}
```

Most of this method again comes directly from Xavier's presentation and it is clear to see that the method $update->createDocument() does not return the correct type. In fact it returns an instance of the my php object. Does anyone know where I am going wrong here? Another thing that might be of help is that even when I try to pass a Solarium Document directly I get an exception.

```
 foreach ($items as $item) {
        $rw_item = new \Solarium_Document_ReadWrite();
        $documents[] = $item->toSolrDocument($rw_item);
    }
```

The exception is

> FatalErrorException: Error: Class 'Solarium_Document_ReadWrite' not found in

I can't seem to find this class in any of the bundles and I am wondering if my setup might be causing the issues. Any help would be very much appreciated.

One additional point to note is that when I am running the solr jar I see the query requests come in from my symfony2 page it is only this indexing action that I can not work out so the config may be alright and I am miss understanding the use of the bundle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use the correct class for the argument.

```
use Solarium\QueryType\Select\Result\AbstractDocument;

...

public function toSolrDocument(AbstractDocument $doc)
{
```

You could also not type hint it:

```
public function toSolrDocument($doc)
{
```

Comment: Thanks. I changed Solarium_Document_ReadWrite to be \Solarium\QueryType\Update\Query\Document.

Comment: I have run into another problem that you might be able to help with. I want to run multiple sites from the same solr installation. I have set up multiple cores in the solr.xml and can see them in the solr admin. However, in my symfony2 project my config is not loading the set core. Instead I am only getting the default core set in my solr.xml file in the defaultCoreName property. Am I missing another obvious one here?